All my windows and UI disappeared

How do I fix this? I need to see the entire UI.

There's generally a couple buttons at the top that toggle some of the UI

You may have accidentally pressed Ctrl + Spacebar
That keyboard shortcut toggles the maximization of the area. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/blender_default.html
Press that keyboard combination again to toggle it off.

If all else fails, you can save your .blend file, close Blender, relaunch it, and do File > Open, but this time opt not to load the UI.
The .blend will load with the interface remaining as you have it in your startup file.

Above: Untick the "Load UI" checkbox.
This is in the file browser on the right panel. If you don't see that panel at first, press N to expand it.

I found that Ctrl + Alt + Spacebar does the same thing as Ctrl + Spacebar: Toggle Maximize Area.
But! If you used Ctrl + Alt + Spacebar to Toggle Maximize Area, you have to use Ctrl + Alt + Spacebar to toggle it back. That is, Ctrl + Spacebar won't do. And viceversa.
Note: Alt Gr + Spacebar is the same thing as Ctrl + Alt + Spacebar.
I accidentally pressed Alt Gr + Spacebar (On Blender 3.6, Windows 10), searched online, found about Ctrl + Spacebar in this page, and it didn't help me. I tried Ctrl + Alt + Spacebar thinking it could have been a keyboard issue, and that worked. On Blender 4.3 it works the same way, I tried before posting this answer.
